# Python pip2 installs packages in /usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/

Tags: python, pip

On LINUX, I have a python2 script that needs 5 python modules to be installed.

So I run :
`sudo -H pip2 install ipython numpy pandas scipy termcolor`

but instead of installing the python modules in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` that got installed in `/usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/`

Therefore, If I run the script needing these 5 modules, it says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toto.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pandas #pour importer les data
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Can you please help me ?

EDIT : Added a few information

```
$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
$ pip2 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the pip2 script you run is from your pypy installation (environment). You can check it by running `pip2 --version` which will show you its path.

To install packages to another environment you need either specify full path to pip (like `sudo /usr/local/lib/python2.7/bin/pip ...`) or, better, modify you PATH environment (see `echo $PATH`) so that python2 will precede pypy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check this tonigth when I get home and I'll let you know